# Why the decimal points of query results are different when using different execution methods for Apache IoTDB?

Tags: python, dbeaver, apache-iotdb, iotdb

For the same query SQL statement running in Apache IoTDB, there is only one decimal point of the query result when executed by the CLI client of IoTDB and dbeaver. However, there are four decimal points of the results when executed by Python. What may be the reason for this difference?

Comment: Do you mean decimal *places*? You're never going to get four decimal *points* out of SQL, or most other things either.

Answer (score 0):

The default datatype of floating point in Python is `double`. If `float` type data is stored in Apache IoTDB, there will be process of converting `float` to `double` datatype when querying using Python API, so the accuracy may change. To avoid this situation, you can save these data as `double` datatype in IoTDB.